# How to condition arguments of a pure function?

Tags: function-construction, conditional, pure-function

I would  like to exclude the point `{x=0,y=0}` in  the function definition

```
f = Function[{x, y}, {x/(x^2 + y^2), -(y/(x^2 + y^2))}]
```

So far I tried `ConditionalExpression`and `/;` without success.

Thanks!

Comment: What should happen for `f[0,0]`?

Comment: Function shouldn't be applied to ` {0,0}` or should return `Null`!

Comment: Assuming it needs to be a pure function for some reason, I guess your only real option is to use `If` or similar to do the check. As far as I am aware, `Function` will always evaluate when it is applied to something. Depending on the amount of conditions, you could use e.g. `Replace[{##},{{0,0}->Null,{x_,y_}:>{x^2,y^2}}]&` or `Replace[{##},{{x_,y_}/;x!=0||y!=0:>{x^2,y^2},_->Null}]&` to have a syntax more similar to traditional downvalue definitions

Comment: @LukasLang Thank you for your assistance. My purpose is to use the pure function inside `TransformedRegion`. A possible workaround could be the definition of a region thereby excluding the point `{0,0}` .

Comment: If you're using it in `TransformedRegion`, I don't recommend using the return value `Null`. It's probably not the correct return for "this thing doesn't exists". `Undefined` is probably better. `Null` is a programmatic value, not a mathematical one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot have a pure function that holds its arguments depending on a condition on the arguments. `Condition` specifically works with pattern matching and pure functions don't use the pattern matcher. So the behaviour that `f[0, 0]` doesn't evaluate simply cannot be achieved with a pure function.

The alternative is some sort of default return value. Probably the easiest way to do this, is with something like `If`, `Switch` or `Which`:

```
f = Function[{x, y},
  If[ TrueQ[x == 0 || y == 0],
   Undefined,
   {x/(x^2 + y^2), -(y/(x^2 + y^2))}
   ]
 ];
f[0, 0]
```

> Undefined

Note the use of `TrueQ`, which is necessary to deal with the case `f[a, b]` where `a` and `b` are symbols. The `If` will not evaluate otherwise, since `a == 0` and `b == 0`  remain unevaluated (because they are equation, not truth statements). The test `x === 0` is not useful here either, since `0. === 0` evaluates to `False`. `PossibleZeroQ[x]` is another test you could use in the `If` statement.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I didn't know `Undefined`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fun variant on Sjoerd's approach using `#0` as a recursive reference

```
f = Function[
   With[{x = #1, y = #2},
    If[TrueQ[x == 0 || y == 0], 
     Unevaluated @@ Hold[#0[##]],
     {x/(x^2 + y^2), -(y/(x^2 + y^2))}
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

This gives

```
f[0, 0]

Unevaluated[
  (With[{x = #1, y = #2}, 
     If[TrueQ[x == 0 || y == 0], 
      Unevaluated @@ Hold[#0[##1]], {x/(x^2 + y^2), -(y/(x^2 + y^2))}]] &)[0, 0]
  ]
```