# An anonymous function with constraints

Tags: function-construction, conditional, pure-function

I'm not very good at working with anonymous functions, a fact that has now come back to bite me.  Suppose I have a function defined as follows:

```
Clear[g]
g[x_] := Sin[x] /; x < 2
```

Then, for example,

```
{g[0.4], g[2.4]} = {0.389418, g[2.4]}
```

Now suppose I want to make  g  into an anonymous function.  Naively, I would write

```
Clear[g]
g := Function[u, Sin[u] /; u < 2]
```

But then

```
{g[0.3], g[2.4]} = {0.29552 /; 0.3 < 2, 0.675463 /; 2.4 < 2}
```

which is clearly not correct.  How do I handle this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to condition arguments of a pure function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203464/how-to-condition-arguments-of-a-pure-function)

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but it's likely not possible!  See the duplicate above.

Comment: imho... I think u should use [Piecewise](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) function to define (zero/[Undefined](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Undefined.html)) output for x >= 2 .

Answer (score 5):

Using `Defer`:

```
ClearAll[g];

g = If[# < 2, Sin[#], Defer[g[#]], Defer[g[#]]] &;

{g[0.4], g[2.4], g[x]}
```

> ```
> {0.389418, g[2.4], g[x]}
> ```

```
Plot[g[x], {x, -Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

> [image: output]

```
 $Version
```

> ```
> "12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)"
> ```

Of course, `g` here isn't a [pure (or "anonymous") function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperations.html#17469) as [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) stresses in his [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/252918/280): it is a `Symbol` with the value of a `Function` containing in its body this `Symbol` itself.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is a version that works correctly with replacements (an answer to  [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)'s [concern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252892/an-anonymous-function-with-constraints/252916?noredirect=1#comment632098_252916)):

```
ClearAll[g];

g /: Defer[g[x_]] := Block[{g`$inDefer = True}, g[x]] /; Not[TrueQ@g`$inDefer]
g = If[TrueQ[# < 2], Sin[#], Defer[g[#]]] &;

{g[0.4], g[2.4], g[x]}
{g[0.4], g[2.4], g[x]} /. x -> 1.
```

> ```
> {0.389418, g[2.4], g[x]}
> ```

> ```
> {0.389418, g[2.4], 0.841471}
> ```

Comment: I thought of this, but from my point of view `g[x]^2 /. x -> 1.2` does not work the way I think it should.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Please see the UPDATE section.

Answer (score 5):

An "anonymous" function should have no name (symbol) attached. ***What result should you want from `g[2.4]` if the result should not contain the symbol `g`?*** I picked up my programming on the street, so take with a grain of salt: My claim is that is should not be `g[2.4]`; rather, if `g = func[...]`, then it should be `func[...][2.4]`, where `func` is a version of `Function` that conditionally evaluates its input.  See an example below.

A so-called function like `g[x_] := Sin[x] /; x < 2`
defines a conditional pattern replacement in an expression with head `g`.
The pattern language is rather complex, even if we stick to down values.
***Exactly what sort of pattern replacements do you want to turn into anonymous functions?*** Well, in the example below, I will keep it simple and implement a single conditional test equivalent to `g[x_,...] := body /; test` like in the OP. I'm not sure it's worth being able to turn `g[Sin[Optional[v_?NumericQ]*u_]] := u + v /; v > 0` into an anonymous function.

`Function[{x,...}, body][x1,...]` makes a literal, unconditional replacement in the  expression `body`, in which each literal occurrence of `x` is replaced by `x1` and so on; this is then evaluated after `Function` returns.  Viewed as a pattern replacement, it's very limited. It seems ill-suited to adapting to complicated patterns.

**Examples.**

*First approach.*

It's probably better to remove `attr` from the definition.  See below.

```
ClearAll[fFunction];
SetAttributes[fFunction, HoldAll];
fFunction[v_, body_, attr_, test_][a___] :=  
  Function[v, body, attr][a] /; Function[v, test, attr][a];
```

Test case:

```
g = fFunction[u, Sin[u], {}, u < 2]
(* fFunction[u, Sin[u], {}, u < 2]  *)

{g[0.3], g[2.4], g[x]}
% /. x -> 1.2
(*
{0.29552,
 fFunction[u, Sin[u], {}, u < 2][2.4], 
 fFunction[u, Sin[u], {}, u < 2][x]}

{0.29552,
 fFunction[u, Sin[u], {}, u < 2][2.4],
 0.932039}
*)
```

*Hey, do attributes really work?*

*HoldAll.*
No, attributes don't really work.
Here's a way to fix it for `HoldAll` and similar.
It destroys somewhat the desired behavior when `test` is not `True`.
Since attributes are not applied to subvalues, `fFunction[x, body, HoldAll, x > 10][a]` won't hold `a`. We have to take advantage of the fact that heads are evaluated first to grab `Hold` of `a` before it evaluates.

```
ClearAll[fFunction];
SetAttributes[fFunction, HoldAll];
fFunction[v_, body_, attr_, test_] := 
  Function[Null,
   fFunction[v, body, attr, test, Hold][Hold[##]], 
   HoldAll];
fFunction[v_, body_, attr_, test_, Hold][Hold[a___]] :=
  Function[v, body, attr][a] /; Function[v, test, attr][a];
```

Now what about `Listable`? Well, that's tricky because we have to thread the evaluation of `test` and use it to block or allow the evaluation of `body` -- that is, `fFunction` should be listable, in the case where `Listable` is in `attr`....Hmm, I'm reminded of something someone one wrote:

> ...once you run into a limitation like this, it is best to reconsider the design and find some other approach to the problem... -- Leonid Shifrin, [How do you set attributes on SubValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-do-you-set-attributes-on-subvalues/545#545)

Remarkably, there's an obvious alternative. Use the standard way of defining functions with patterns. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

g := If[#1 < 2, Sin[#1], HoldForm[g[#1]], HoldForm[g[#1]]] &

{g[0.4], g[2.4], g[x]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Will this work for you?

```
g[x_ /; x < 2] := Function[u, Sin[u]][x]
{g[0.4], g[2.4]}
(* {0.389418, g[2.4]} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203464/how-to-condition-arguments-of-a-pure-function)). It gives the "proper" result but I'm not sure you really want this result...

```
g = If[TrueQ[#1 < 2], Sin[#1], Unevaluated @@ Hold[#0[#1]]] &;
{g[0.4], g[2.4], g[x]}

{0.389418, 
 Unevaluated[(If[TrueQ[#1 < 2], Sin[#1], Unevaluated @@ Hold[#0[#1]]] &)[2.4]], 
 Unevaluated[(If[TrueQ[#1 < 2], Sin[#1], Unevaluated @@ Hold[#0[#1]]] &)[x]]
 }
```